# How can I send part of JSON string between AS3 and nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, actionscript-3, sockets

I have JSON string that I get from AS3, and I need to send part of it, for example:

```
{"player": "player", "x_accel": "10", "y_accel": "10"}
```

And I want to send only x_accel, because that was the only thing that changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Backbone Model. From Backbone Model.save doc:

"If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call model.save(attrs, {patch: true}). You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes."

Comment: At the client side, I use AS3, so I don't really see how I can use backbone. I just don't understand.

Comment: It's not straightforward indeed but this might help: http://jessewarden.com/2012/08/backbone-js-for-flash-and-flex-developers.html